# Error while I try to install xvfb

Tags: apt, security, 20.10, xvfb

I am trying to install the `xvfb` package and I get the following error:

```
sudo apt install xvfb
[sudo] password for d1-user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xvfb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
Need to get 786 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.291 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/universe amd64 xvfb amd64 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xorg-server/xvfb_1.20.9-2ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Hello.  Did you do as it says in your question and try these 2 things? < maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing>

Comment: @David the version is `20.10`. I tried both the suggestions but I still get the same error

Comment: OK. It does not say you tried the 2 fixes in the question. Maybe a good idea to update the question with this info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)